# Make iframe fill remaining height of div in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a div which contains another `div` of unknown `height` and an `iframe`.

I want to make the `iframe` fill the remaining height of the parent `div`. After a lot of searching the only way I've found to do this is by using **CSS** tables which works in every browser except IE.

This is the HTML I'm using:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top">
        <div style="height: 100px; background: yellow">Top bar</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <iframe />
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.top {
    display: table-row;
}

.bottom {
    /* changing this to table-row works correctly except the iframe no longer expands to the full height in IE */
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}

iframe {
    background:red;
    height:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HTq47/) (Changed the iframe to a div)

In non-IE browsers, the iframe fills the remaining space. In IE the `iframe` height is set to the same height as the `.container`. So the full height ends up being the height of the `.container` plus the height of `.top`.

This image might explain a bit better:

[image]

IE has set the height of the iframe to the full table height but as `.top` has a height too, it makes the table become larger than the specified height.

Is there anyway to fix this without using JS? I don't want to use JS as it means making sure it updates when things are resized, inserted, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try `height:100%; auto` and see what that does

Comment: Doesn't help, changing either of the heights to auto stops it from expanding.